# Typescript – setting type of first and second item in an array interface

Tags: typescript

I have been using interfaces for incoming JSON and it works a real treat. Unfortunately, this API is passing data as three arrays

```
{
  price: [[date, number],[date, number],...],
  cap: [[date, number],[date, number],...],
  volume: [[date, number],[date, number],...],
}
```

I'm wondering if there is some way for me to use an interface to capture this scenario without writing a whole new class.

```
interface Foo {
  price: [date, number][];
  cap: [date, number][];
  volume: [date, number][];
}
```

And if not, is there an easy way to write a class that works as effortlessly as an interface?

Comment: Do you mean "whole new interface"?

Comment: What do you want to get here: compile-time hints (for known data type) or run-time checks (for unknown exactly, but expected one)?

Comment: I honestly don’t know the difference. When I use interfaces it will give me IDE hints and compile errors but they fail gracefully in production

Comment: Unional I am asking how to do this without writing a class with a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this

```
interface MyList {
    [index: number]: any;
    0: Date;
    1: string;
}
const t: MyList = [new Date(), 'toto', 4, {}]; // work
const t: MyList = [1, '2', 4, {}]; // fails
const t: MyList = [1, {}, 4, {}]; // fails
```

I hope that can help you

Comment: That did it nicely. Only change I made was `[index: number]: Date | string;` but I don't know if it makes a difference in practice